# Char comparison with 0xFF returns false even when it is equal to it, why?

Tags: c++, char, int

In C++ program I have some `char buf[256]`. The problem is here:

```
if (buf[pbyte] >= 0xFF)
    buf[++pbyte] = 0x00;
```

This always returns false even when `buf[pbyte]` is equal to 255 AKA 0xFF as seen in immediate window and watch window. Thus the statement does not get executed. However, when I change this to below:

```
if (buf[pbyte] >= char(0xFF))
    buf[++pbyte] = 0x00;
```

The program works; how come?

Comment: According to the C++ language specification, a `char` type has a maximum guaranteed range of 255.  There can't be a value greater than the maximum.

Comment: `char` usually ranges between -128 and +127. Odds are good it can never reach 255.

Comment: I first used == then I used >= but no help. Eventually I used char(0xFF) rather than 0xFF on its own. It seems that when 0xFF is treated as in int and not casted to char, the code fails. If I cast 0xFF to char then it works whether I use >= or ==

Comment: ok, but -1 in char would be 0xFF isn't it where all bits are set? why is 0xFF not treated as -1? what am I missing here?

Comment: a raw 0xFF is an `int`. 255 is just fine for an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The literal `0xFF` is treated as an `int` with the value 255.

When you compare a `char` to an `int`, the `char` is promoted to an `int` before the comparison.

On some platforms `char` is a signed value with a range like -128 to +127.  On other platforms `char` is an unsigned value with a range like 0 to 255.

If your platform's `char` is signed, and its bit pattern is 0xFF, then it's probably -1.  Since -1 is a valid `int`, the promotion stops there.

You end up comparing -1 to 255.

The solution is to eliminate the implicit conversions.  You can write the comparison as:

```
if (buf[pbyte] == '\xFF') ...
```

Now both sides are `char`s, so they'll be promoted in the same manner and are directly comparable.

Comment: *"If your platform's char is signed, and its bit pattern is 0xFF, then it's -1."* That's implementation defined.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen:  OK, I added the hedge word "probably" to address that.  However, `char` is so constrained by the current standard, that an implementation cannot use anything but two's complement.  (Signed magnitude, for example, could only represent -127 to 127, yet the standard requires the range be at least 256 distinct values.)

Comment: I believe [-127,127] was legal in C++98. Could be wrong though. Anyways, it's fine now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `char` is signed on your system.

In the common 2s complement representation, a signed `char` with the "byte-value" 0xFF represents the integer `-1`, while `0xFF` is an `int` with value 255. Thus, you are effectively comparing `int(-1) >= int(255)`, which yields false. Keep in mind that they are compared as `int` because of arithmetic conversion rules, that is both operands are promoted ("cast implicitly") to `int` before comparing.

If you write `char(0xFF)` however, you do end up with the comparison `-1 >= -1`, which yields true as expected.

If you want to store numbers in the range [0,255], you should use `unsigned char` or `std::uint8_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: The problem is that the code doesn't account for the possibility that `char` is signed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the integer promotions in this condition

```
if (buf[pbyte] >= `0xFF`)
```

the two operands are converted to the type `int` (more precisely only the left operand is converted to an object of the type `int` because the right operand already has the type `int`). As it seems in your system the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char` then the value `'\xFF'` is a negative value equal to -1.  Then this value is converted to an object of the type `int` you will get `0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming that the type `int` occupies 4 bytes).

On the other hand the integer constant `0xFF` is a positive value that has internal representation like `0x000000FF`

Thus the condition in the if statement

```
if ( 0xFFFFFFFF >= `0x000000FF`)
```

yields false.

When you use the casting `( char )0xFF` then the both operands have the same type and the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Integer literals by default are converted to an `int`, assuming the value will fit into the `int` type, otherwise it is promoted to a `long`.

So in your code you are specifying `0xFF` which is interpreted as an `int` type, i.e. `0x000000FF`